# What is the spell or charm used to send an object from one place to another?

Tags: harry-potter, spells

Is there a known spell or charm from the wizarding world that can accurately allow an item to be sent to a specific destination?

E.g. the charm used for 'interdepartmental memos' within the Ministry of Magic.

Comment: @Valorum I believe the OP is asking if there is a spell to send an object to an exact location with 100% accuracy whereas most spells require the wizard to aim i.e. spell goes where the wand is pointing. It isn't exactly clear though.

Comment: Harry Potter book 27: Voldemort gets tired of Harry's shit and just sends him a faked Hogwarts letter containing a captured Avada Kedavra.

Comment: Yes, sorry for the poor wording. I'm looking for a spell which will allow an item to be sent accurately to a specific target. For some context, I am a keen darts players and thought it would be a nice touch to to have an accuracy charm inscribed on my darts.

Comment: Yeah. If that spell or similar is ever referenced at any point.

Comment: Much clearer now, thank you. Marked for reopening.

Answer (score 2):

## The closest spell which matches your description is the Banishing Spell.

Looking at your original question, it looks like you're familiar with this one. It's the only spell mentioned in the books which sends items away from the caster (although there is of course Wingardium Leviosa, which levitates objects).

> They were supposed to be practising the opposite of the Summoning Charm today - the Banishing Charm. Owing to the potential for nasty accidents when objects kept flying across the room, Professor Flitwick had given each student a stack of cushions on which to practise, the theory being that these wouldn't hurt anyone if they went off target. It was a good theory, but it wasn't working well. Neville's aim was so poor that he kept accidentally sending much heavier things flying across the room - Professor Flitwick, for instance.
>   <sub>*(Goblet of Fire, Chapter 26, The Second Task)*.</sub>

As you can see, this spell was not immune from faulty wandwork. It isn't a spell which *guarantees* the object will reach its destination, however.

There is no 'accuracy spell' in Harry Potter. The issue with looking for one is that *all* magic in Harry Potter is dependant on the proficiency of the spellcaster, how well they're concentrating, the wand they're using, that wand's relationship to the wizard, and a dozen other factors. There's no spell which is guaranteed to work perfectly every time. There can be faulty wandwork at play with even the simplest of spells. So 'accurately' is really just a measure for how skilled the wizard is and how well they've mastered the spell. Neville isn't skilled (at this point) and hasn't mastered the spell, so he screws up.

This spell is the best candidate for what you're looking for. Like the Summoning Charm, it can be used for more than just sending cushions flying around a room. It can send items long-distance as well.

> "Just as long as it works tomorrow," Harry said. "The Firebolt's going to be much further away than the stuff in here, it's going to be in the castle, and I'm going to be out there in the grounds..."
>   "That doesn't matter," said Hermione firmly. "Just as long as you're concentrating really, really hard on it, it'll come."
>   <sub>*(Goblet of Fire, Chapter 20, The First Task)*.</sub>

The Banishing Spell may be the spell which is used on the Ministry memos, or it could be an unknown spell. At any rate, it seems that the memos are enchanted to move from office to office rather than being sent by magic individually by each sender.

> Once again the lift doors opened and four or five witches and wizards got out; at the same time, several paper aeroplanes swooped into the lift. Harry stared up at them as they flapped idly around above his head; they were a pale violet colour and he could see *Ministry of Magic* stamped along the edge of their wings.
>   "Just inter-departmental memos," Mr Weasley muttered to him. "We used to use owls, but the mess was unbelievable...droppings all over the desks..."
>   <sub>*(Order of the Phoenix, Chapter 7, The Ministry of Magic)*.</sub>

Comment: "Its not Wengardium Leviosa its Wingarium Leviosa!!!" (Quoting Hermione Granger) But that's really interesting, +1 because that's a spell not many people know about!

Comment: @lightofdeanthomas Actually, it's leviooooooooooosaaa. Thanks, nice catch. I'll edit. Also, most interesting username that I've come across for a while. What is it about Dean Thomas that you find so incandescent?

Comment: Thanks, I had indeed already found this one, was hoping there was something I had missed somewhere.

Comment: @Kev Sorry, there's not as far as I'm aware.